# In R, how to display value on the links/paths of Sankey Graph?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, networkd3

**Background**

I was trying the create a Sankey graph like the following figure. Actually, I wanted to get a output where values (10, 20, 30, 40) will be set in the paths (from one node to another node).

[image]

**How Did I Try?**

At first, I tried using the [Plotly library](https://plotly.com/javascript/sankey-diagram/) of Python. However, somewhere I have seen that it is not possible to set the values in the links or the paths of Sankey graph in Plotly (of Python). Later, I switched to R (for some other reasons also) where more resources are available (I think). However, here, I am also facing the same problem. I have checked many tutorials (e.g., [this one](https://www.displayr.com/sankey-diagrams-r/)), Q&A (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850226/highlight-all-connected-paths-from-start-to-end-of-a-sankey-diagram-using-networ), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911437/is-there-any-way-to-show-label-on-the-links-in-sankey-graph-echarts), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472965/is-there-any-r-function-to-visualize-the-values-of-the-links-as-text-inside-the)) of SO which are in `R`. Still, I could not to find a tutorial or resources where the values are displayed in the paths!

**My Question**

How can I display the values on the links/paths of Sankey Graph, in R?

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916538/add-text-within-links-in-d3-js-sankey-diagram) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57745314/how-to-add-value-labels-on-the-flows-item-of-a-alluvial-sankey-plot-on-r-ggallu) questions of SO seems to be similar. However, I failed to understand the way to incorporate those in my codes.

**Example Code** (collected from [here](https://www.displayr.com/sankey-diagrams-r/))

```
# install.packages('networkD3')
library(networkD3)
nodes = data.frame("name" = 
 c("Node A", # Node 0
 "Node B", # Node 1
 "Node C", # Node 2
 "Node D"))# Node 3
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
 0, 1, 10, # Each row represents a link. The first number
 0, 2, 20, # represents the node being conntected from. 
 1, 3, 30, # the second number represents the node connected to.
 2, 3, 40),# The third number is the value of the node
 byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))
names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")


 sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
 Source = "source", Target = "target",
 Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
 fontSize= 50, nodeWidth = 30)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved by injecting custom JavaScript code when it's rendered using `htmlwidgets::onRender()`. The example below will initially position the link labels appropriately, but if the nodes are manually moved, the link labels will not automatically update accordingly. To achieve that, you would probably have to also override the default `dragmove` behaviour.

```r
library(htmlwidgets)
library(networkD3)

nodes <- 
  data.frame(
    name = c("Node A", "Node B", "Node C", "Node D")
  )

links <- 
  data.frame(
    source = c(0, 0, 1, 2),
    target = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
    value = c(10, 20, 30, 40)
  )

p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                   Source = "source", Target = "target",
                   Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   fontSize= 20, nodeWidth = 30)

htmlwidgets::onRender(p, '
  function(el) { 
    var nodeWidth = this.sankey.nodeWidth();
    var links = this.sankey.links();
        
    links.forEach((d, i) => {
      var startX = d.source.x + nodeWidth;
      var endX = d.target.x;
      
      var startY = d.source.y + d.sy + d.dy / 2;
      var endY = d.target.y + d.ty + d.dy / 2;
      
      d3.select(el).select("svg g")
        .append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("x", startX + ((endX - startX) / 2))
        .attr("y", startY + ((endY - startY) / 2))
        .text(d.value);
    })
  }
')
```

[image]

Comment: CJ Yetman, can you please let me know how can I save the generated figure as an image? Though I can properly save the output as an HTML file, I fail to save it properly (can not save the figure having values) as an image. `saveWidget(html_widget, 'file_sankey.html')
library(webshot)
webshot("file_sankey.html","file_sankey.png")`. Here, `html_widget = htmlwidgets::onRender(p,......`

Comment: Search Stack Overflow. I’ve answered this several times before. It’s not straightforward and does not fit in a comment.